# Is it possible to Get clicked row value and know whether row is selected or not in lightning:datatable

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-datatable, datatable

In lightning:datatable, is it possible to know whether the row is checked or unchecked if yes, then which row using keyfield?

In lightning datatable I have modified the onrowselection event to accommodate my custom search. Now on unchecking row, I'm not able to remove selected row. Want to see if it is possible if we can get the clicked row detail and if it is checked or unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, while selecting row for the first time, you can save them in an attribute. Say , `selectedRow`.

When you are deselecting or selecting row again then you can check which previously selected field is deselected by comparing `selectedRow` with newly selected rows

For example:

```
handleSelect : function(component, event, helper) {
    var previousSelectedRows=component.get("v.selectedRow");
    var selectedRows = event.getParam('selectedRows'); 
    var  unselectedRowIds= [];
    for ( var i = 0; i < previousSelectedRows.length; i++ ) {
        var isPresent=false;
        for(var j = 0; j < selectedRows.length; j++ ){
            if(selectedRows[j].Id===previousSelectedRows[i].Id){
                isPresent=true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!isPresent){
            unselectedRowIds.push(previousSelectedRows[i].Id);
        }
    }
    if(previousSelectedRows.length > 0){
        console.log(unselectedRowIds); // this will print deselected row Id
    }
    component.set("v.selectedRow", selectedRows);
}
```